# Generate form classes in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm building an onboarding / setup flow, and I'd like to define the fields, strings, etc. in a dict and have the form on each page automatically generated.

forms.py currently has:

```
class OnboardingEducationForm(forms.Form):
  school_1 = forms.CharField(label='School Name(s)', max_length=100, required=False)
  school_2 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
  school_3 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
```

How would I generate those classes automatically from a json file that looks like this:

```
setup_content = {
    "form": {
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "school_1",
                "args": {
                    "label": "School Name(s)",
                    "max_length": "100",
                    "required": "False",
                },

            },
            {
                "name": "school_2",
                "args": {
                    "max_length": "100",
                    "required": "False",
                },
            },
            {
                "name": "school_3",
                "args": {
                    "max_length": "100",
                    "required": "False",
                },
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Note: This is *not* for a model form. I'm using `modelform_factory` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can try like this(by overriding the `__init__()` method):

```
FIELDS = setup_content['forms']['fields']

class OnboardingEducationForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OnboardingEducationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in FIELDS:
             self.fields[field['name']] = forms.CharField(**field['args'])
```